# Why one defines the proper complexity functions?

Tags: computational-complexity, computability

**Definition:**
A proper complexity function is a function $f$ mapping a natural number to a natural number such that:

1. $f$ is nondecreasing
2. There exists a $k$-string Turing machine $M$ such that on any input of
   length $n$, $M$ halts after $O(n + f(n))$ steps, uses $O(f(n))$ space, and
   outputs $f(n)$ consecutive blanks.

---

I don't understand why one should introduce such a type of functions to define time or space bounds. For example if I write an algorithm for a Turing machine, why  can't I use a generic function $g:\mathbb N\longrightarrow \mathbb N$ to measure the amount of steps?

Ok, the condition $1.$ is clear, in fact the number of steps must increase but what about the condition $2.$?

Comment: How are you going to use less than $O(n)$ space, if you already used $n$ cells for the input itself? There are ways of thinking about those kinds of classes, but it requires a more complicated setup than a single-tape Turing Machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Proper complexity function" is not, as far as I'm aware, standard terminology. In my experience the concept you define is more often called a [constructible function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructible_function), or "time-constructible".

Certainly there's nothing morally deficient about using non-constructible functions to measure resource usage of an algorithm you write (which the word "proper" might suggest to some).

However, there are some technical results where you **start** with a complexity class and **get** a problem or a program that relates in a particular way to that complexity class. Typical examples are the [time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_hierarchy_theorem) and [space hierarchy theorems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_hierarchy_theorem). For these theorems it is necessary that the function you start out with is sufficiently well-behaved that the constructions in their proofs are possible, and the definition you quote nicely ensures that a "proper" function is "sufficiently well-behaved" for most of these hierarchy results.

Comment: "Proper complexity function" is used in Papadimitriou's book on computational complexity, and [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proper_complexity_function) gives another reference.